# Ingress is not getting address on GKE and GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When creating ingress, no address is generated and when viewed from GKE dashboard it is always in the `Creating ingress` status.
Describing the ingress does not show any events and I can not see any clues on GKE dashboard.

Has anyone has a similar issue or any suggestions on how to debug?

My deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mobile-gateway-ingress    
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: mobile-gateway-service
    servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mobile-gateway-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: mobile-gateway
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mobile-gateway-deployment
  labels:
    app: mobile-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mobile-gateway
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mobile-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mobile-gateway
        image: eu.gcr.io/my-project/mobile-gateway:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

Describing ingress shows no events:

```
mobile-gateway ➤ kubectl describe ingress mobile-gateway-ingress                                                                                                                         git:master*
Name:             mobile-gateway-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  mobile-gateway-service:80 (10.4.1.3:8080,10.4.2.3:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     mobile-gateway-service:80 (10.4.1.3:8080,10.4.2.3:8080)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"mobile-gateway-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"backend":{"serviceName":"mobile-gateway-service","servicePort":80}}}

Events:  <none>
hello ➤
```

With a simple LoadBalancer service, an IP address is given. The problem is only with the ingress resource.

Comment: I have followed the example https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer line for line and again I have an ingress without address and stuck in state `Creating ingress`

Comment: Can you please run `kubectl describe ingess NAME`?  The events section of this output may show an issue like you hit your Backends or IP Addresses quota.

Comment: It's very strange that ingress description doesn't give you any events. Even when you describe it after like 5 minutes there are no events?

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan Added output from describe, unfortunately no events.

Comment: @suren This ingress has been "Creating" all weekend and still no events :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem in this case was I had did not include the addon `HttpLoadBalancing` when creating the cluster!
My fault but was would have been noice to have an event informing me of this mistake in the ingress resource.

Strange that when I created a new cluster to follow the tutorial cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer using default addons including `HttpLoadBalancing` that I observed the same issue. Maybe I didn't wait long enough? Anyway, working now that I have included the addon.

Comment: `HttpLoadBalancing` is included in the clusters by default. If you specified `--enable-addons` flag, then you might need to list this add-on in there as well, but if you follow the tutorial without modifying the steps, you should be getting this add-on.

Comment: I have the `HttpLoadBalancing` add-on enabled on my cluster but my ingress is stuck in the "Creating Ingress" state for days. Any ideas

Comment: @AhmetB-Google, I followed the tutorial after creating my cluster from the GCP dashboard, but facing the same issue

Comment: The command to use `gcloud container clusters create gara-cluster --zone=europe-west1-b  --addons=HttpLoadBalancing`

Answer (score 4):

To complete the accepted answer, it's worth noting that it's possible to activate the addon on an already existing cluster (from the Google console).

However, it **will restart** your cluster **with downtime** (in my case, it took several minutes on an almost empty cluster). Be sure that's acceptable in your case, and do tests.

Comment: (This might have been a comment on the accepted answer instead.)
In my case, enabling the addon only caused the control plane (master) to restart - the nodes remained up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Ingress configuration was bad! Run `kubectl describe ingress` and look for errors. You'll probably need to know about `kubectl delete -f` as well, which is the opposite of `kubectl apply -f` (use this after you find your errors in the `.yml` files)