# How to list addons in a running cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I was looking for a solution to ingress not showing an address.

```
@cloudshell:~ ()$ kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   nginx   *                 80      85m
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223937/ingress-is-not-getting-address-on-gke-and-gce#comment89491118_51251806) comment, HttpLoadBalancing is included by default. I wanted to verify it and typed `minikube addons list`.

```
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------|
|         ADDON NAME          |           MAINTAINER           |
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------|
| ambassador                  | 3rd party (Ambassador)         |
| auto-pause                  | Google                         |
| cloud-spanner               | Google                         |
| csi-hostpath-driver         | Kubernetes                     |
| dashboard                   | Kubernetes                     |
| default-storageclass        | Kubernetes                     |
| efk                         | 3rd party (Elastic)            |
| freshpod                    | Google                         |
| gcp-auth                    | Google                         |
| gvisor                      | Google                         |
| headlamp                    | 3rd party (kinvolk.io)         |
| helm-tiller                 | 3rd party (Helm)               |
| inaccel                     | 3rd party (InAccel             |
|                             | [info@inaccel.com])            |
| ingress                     | Kubernetes                     |
| ingress-dns                 | Google                         |
| istio                       | 3rd party (Istio)              |
| istio-provisioner           | 3rd party (Istio)              |
| kong                        | 3rd party (Kong HQ)            |
| kubevirt                    | 3rd party (KubeVirt)           |
| logviewer                   | 3rd party (unknown)            |
| metallb                     | 3rd party (MetalLB)            |
| metrics-server              | Kubernetes                     |
| nvidia-driver-installer     | Google                         |
| nvidia-gpu-device-plugin    | 3rd party (Nvidia)             |
| olm                         | 3rd party (Operator Framework) |
| pod-security-policy         | 3rd party (unknown)            |
| portainer                   | 3rd party (Portainer.io)       |
| registry                    | Google                         |
| registry-aliases            | 3rd party (unknown)            |
| registry-creds              | 3rd party (UPMC Enterprises)   |
| storage-provisioner         | Google                         |
| storage-provisioner-gluster | 3rd party (Gluster)            |
| volumesnapshots             | Kubernetes                     |
|-----------------------------|--------------------------------|
```

It doesn't seem to be there, but I am not sure if Google Cloud uses minikube to manage clusters. I get a profile error when trying to enable the addon.

```
$ minikube addons enable HttpLoadBalancing

X Exiting due to MK_ADDON_ENABLE: loading profile: cluster "minikube" does not exist
*
```

---

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall#setting_up_a_cluster) command to update addons.

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME \
    --update-addons ConfigConnector=ENABLED
```

`gcloud component list` does not show anything related to HttpLoadBalancing, but I do see it in the cloud console.
[image: httploadbalancing enabled]

Edit:
I also tried going to the external endpoint (=public ip address?), but there is no response.
[image: external endpoint]

```
$ kubectl describe ingress ingress-service
Name:             ingress-service
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /api/users/?(.*)   auth-srv:3000 (10.8.0.194:3000)
              /?(.*)             auth-srv:3000 (10.8.0.194:3000)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:       <none>
```

Edit 2: Ingress status
[image: ingress service]

[image: ingress details]

Comment: Is it also not showing any external IP through ```kubectl describe ingress <ingress-name>```?

Comment: @JamesS No. (edited the question) I did find [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) tutorial, but I am not familiar with Helm. [full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/microservices-quiz-app/tree/5d91e1d7b528038901b546f2bc0cd7f9f6012752) for reference

Comment: Can you also update the case with a screenshot from Kubernetes Engine > Services and Ingress > Ingress tab so we can see the status of the Ingress that you created?

Comment: In order to use the NGINX Ingress resource in Kubernetes, you need to have an Ingress controller deployed in your cluster. An Ingress controller is a component that runs as a Kubernetes pod and listens to the Ingress resource for new rules to route incoming traffic to the appropriate services.

Comment: Based on my findings, if you deploy an Ingress resource without an NGINX Ingress controller as explained in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke#configure_ingress_resource_to_use_nginx_ingress_controller:~:text=Google%20Kubernetes%20Engine-,Deploy%20NGINX%20Ingress%20Controller,-Before%20you%20deploy), the resulting Ingress resource will not have an external IP.

Comment: @JamesS Thank you, I didn't realize there was a distinction between resource and controller. It works now [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75739196/20898396). (My intention was to have 2 questions, one for the addons and one for the ip.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `NGINX Ingress resource` in GKE, you need to have an `Ingress controller` deployed in your cluster. An `Ingress controller` is a component that runs as a Kubernetes pod and listens to the Ingress resource for new rules to route incoming traffic to the appropriate services.

Once the `NGINX Ingress controller` is deployed and running, you can create an `NGINX Ingress resource` to define the routing rules for your services.

Steps on how to configure an NGINX Ingress Controller and how you can make your NGINX Ingress Resource use it is discussed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke#configure_ingress_resource_to_use_nginx_ingress_controller:%7E:text=Google%20Kubernetes%20Engine-,Deploy%20NGINX%20Ingress%20Controller,-Before%20you%20deploy)