# Does setting up an nginx ingress controller require extra steps on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

If I use the default ingress controller, I do obtain an external ip address.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class : "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - # host: quiz-app.com
      http:
        paths:
          # auth service
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

[image: default controller details]

However, if I switch back to using an NGINX controller, I don't obtain an IP address.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / # rewrite /api/users/signup to simply /signup
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - # host: quiz-app.com
      http:
        paths:
          # auth service
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

[image: nginx details]

There is a separate [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) for nginx controllers, but I don't really understand it because 2 clusters are used.

> The GKE Ingress controller creates and configures an HTTP(S) Load
> Balancer according to the information in the Ingress, routing all
> external HTTP traffic (on port 80) to the web NodePort Service you
> exposed. - [source](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#creating_an_ingress_resource)

Are some things not set up automatically when using NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to install an NGINX controller. The .yaml file is only an Ingress Resource, rules that the controller uses. When run locally, an NGINX controller was already present. Since Google uses another controller by default, you need to setup the NGINX controller yourself if you want to use one.
In the Cloud Shell after connecting to your cluster, run the following commands.

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx

kubectl get deployment nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
kubectl get service nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
```

```
NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   0/1     1            0           28s
NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.8.129.239   <pending>     80:31061/TCP,443:31878/TCP   28s
```

Locally, there is a separate namespace for nginx.

```
>kubectl get namespace
NAME                   STATUS   AGE
default                Active   2d21h
ingress-nginx          Active   2d21h
```

There is also a deployment for an ingress controller.

```
>kubectl get deployment -n ingress-nginx
NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           2d21h
```

[credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725450/how-to-list-addons-in-a-running-cluster?noredirect=1#comment133609658_75725450)

In the case of Google Cloud, there is probably a deployment for the default controller, but I am not sure which one it is.

```
$ kubectl get deployment -n kube-system
NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
antrea-controller                         0/0     0            0           32h
antrea-controller-horizontal-autoscaler   1/1     1            1           32h
egress-nat-controller                     1/1     1            1           32h
event-exporter-gke                        1/1     1            1           32h
konnectivity-agent                        5/5     5            5           32h
konnectivity-agent-autoscaler             1/1     1            1           32h
kube-dns                                  2/2     2            2           32h
kube-dns-autoscaler                       1/1     1            1           32h
l7-default-backend                        1/1     1            1           32h
metrics-server-v0.5.2
```